# Are there plans to upgrade to material-ui 3?

Tags: react-admin

The current release uses material-ui 1.x.  I tried upgrading locally but many of the css class paths changed in material-ui 3.

Answer (score 0):

Nope we won't upgrade to material-ui 3. We are waiting for the `4` release.

See https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2399 for a more detailed answer.